# What file to modify atom's C++ grammar?

Tags: c++, editor, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

I want atom to highlight templates/types like vector, map, vec2 etc, so Basically I want to add those as tokens somewhere.

Can I just add my own grammar to replace the default one?

I found this https://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/creating-a-grammar/ but it doesn't explain what file I should modify.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about C++, but if these types are part of the spec and missing from the [official package](https://github.com/atom/language-c), have you considered  proposing them to be added?

If that and using [third-party packages](https://atom.io/packages/search?q=language-cpp) isn't an option, you probably want to extend an existing package. To do so, you can include the grammar from the bundled C++ package into your custom grammar and add to (or overwrite) its patterns.

```
'scopeName': 'source.cpp.custom'
'fileTypes': [
  'cc'
  'cpp'
  'cp'
  'cxx'
  'c++'
  'cu'
  'cuh'
  'h'
  'hh'
  'hpp'
  'hxx'
  'h++'
  'inl'
  'ino'
  'ipp'
  'tcc'
  'tpp'
]
name: "My Custom CPP"
patterns: [
  {
    # include all patterns from the bundled C++ grammar
    include: "source.cpp"
  }
  # add you custom patterns here to extend the bundled grammar
]
```

Should you prefer to extend a non-bundled C++ package, take a look at [atom-package-deps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/atom-package-deps) which allows you to depend on third-party packages.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is not simple.

One must first create a clone package using apm, modify it, and activate it or use it in dev mode. The files are c++.cson and tree-sitter-cpp.cson. Those file are similar when compared to textmate and sublime text.

I asked on their slack channel, there are several steps involved. I don't think it's something one should plan to do because atom has those packages "precompiled" into a big blog of v8 js thing, so you cannot modify the default files directly, you have to tell atom to use a custom package. The problem is that this package, when created, has a node_modules directory with 400+ files in it.

I managed to do it but it felt clumsy so I abandoned using atom entirely, and kept using sublime text.